# source tree showing github login failed(multiple root elements)

Tags: github

I am signing into git hub through source tree and clone my project.

However, it shows

```
Login Failed 
Multiple root elements
Line 2 Position 2
```

How can I avoid this error message?

Comment: What is the url of the GitHub repo you are cloning (if it is not private)